# How to access CGContext for creating CGLayer offscreen

Tags: iphone, cgcontext, cglayer

**Intention:** creating `CGLayer` offscreen, draw some complicated stuff on it from second thread and use it later for quick drawing on main thread

**Problem:**  `CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, size, info)` expects an already existing `CGContext` so that it knows for what kind of context it needs to be optimized.

**Solution I found so far:**  `CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicSetCurrentContext()`
but this function doesn't seem to exist anymore.

**Question:** Isn't there another way to access something like a *default context*? Or do i really need to wait for the first `drawRect:` call just for accessing `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and creating all `CGLayers` from main thread with one wasted drawing run?

Answer (score 1):

you can create an image context by doing something like:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect);
    // your drawing code
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

with that said, i'm not sure you can do this from a thread other than main. worth a try, though.

Comment: that's what I'm currently using. works fine. but the docs says "CGLayer object is a much better representation than a bitmap context" and also that it can be used in much the same way. but how?