# how adding alpha in a region of the uiimageview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, ios6

is it possible to add an alpha property on a region in the same image?
For example

[image: square without alpha]

[image: square with alpha]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to break the image apart and save the alpha as part of a png, then organize the imageviews to be flush against each other.

Otherwise, I wrote this quick code in a regular view that does the same with an image (I'm relatively new to Core Graphics so I'm sure there are better ways of doing this - also, my example the images are side by side):

```
-(void) drawRect {

    // GET THE CONTEXT, THEN FLIP THE COORDS (my view is 189 ponts tall)

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform flip = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 189);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flip);

    // GET THE IMAGE REF

    UIImage *targetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = targetImage.CGImage;

    // SET THE COORDS

    CGRect imageCoords = CGRectMake(0, 0, 116, 189);
    CGRect imageCoordsTwo = CGRectMake(116, 0, 117, 189);

    // CUT UP THE IMAGE INTO TWO IMAGES

    CGImageRef firstImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, imageCoords);
    CGImageRef secondImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, imageCoordsTwo);

    // DRAW FIRST IMAGE, SAVE THE STATE, THEN SET THE TRANSPARENCY AMOUNT

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageCoords, firstImage);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, .4f);

    // DRAW SECOND IMAGE, RESTORE THE STATE

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageCoordsTwo, secondImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // TIDY UP

    CGImageRelease(firstImage);
    CGImageRelease(secondImage);

}
```

Comment: I have the following error when using my image

CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Comment: It sounds to me that you aren't putting the code in a drawRect call or if did, then you must be manually calling it (which you shouldn't do).  If you put it outside the drawRect call, you'll have to create your own context, then extract each image from it once you draw it.  Here's a referring post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637860/how-to-access-cgcontext-for-creating-cglayer-offscreen